# Polishing Metal Rail

Tags: cleaning, deck, metal

I'm hoping someone can identify what type of metal this outside balcony rail is and offer advice on how to polish it.  I tried Brasso.  It did not seem to really do anything.  Possibly I need to scrub with brush?  I used cloth.

So,
1. Anyone know what kind of metal this is?
2. How does one make it look nicer?

Thanks,

Dave[image: Photo of railing]

Comment: It looks like copper to me and the thing I have used is muraitic acid to clean it. It would need to be rinsed of completely or it will turn green again like the Statue of Liberty. Also the acid would tear up anything around it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The metal appears to be copper. There are house hold cleaners for copper bottom pots that will help clean this. Wrights copper cream is a product my Mom uses. You may need a "car buffer" with a cloth bonnet to do a large area. After getting it bright and clean a spray with a clear lacquer will keep it looking nice for several years. Without sealing it will quickly tarnish again. I think lemon juice and baking soda will also work but may take more elbow grease than wrights.

Comment: Thanks!  Any recommendations or names of the "clear lacquer"?

Comment: @Dave as Ed said, Wrights (http://amzn.to/2BuihQg) is the best thing you can use, just know in order for it to work well, you need to warm up the metal. Make sure to have a bucket with warm water, dump the sponge that comes with the cream inside the the water with some of the cream, and soak the rail with the warm water and start rubbing. The metal will look pinkish. Rinse it immediately or wrights will actually stain the metal. Here is a bunch of different clear coats you can try: http://amzn.to/2o0sUmB